# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element "ear"

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am very inexperienced about xml schemas,xsd files and the validation; and I have been developing a xml file for my project.After running the xml validation class, I have `cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ear'` error on the console.
This is the xsd file that I use for validating:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
    xmlns:ea ="http://ea.efa.com" targetNamespace="http://ea .efa.com
    xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" schemaLocation="XAdES.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" schemaLocation="XAdESv141.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="ear">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>ear information</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            //Some stuff
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="faNo">
            <xs:selector xpath="ea:facancel"/>
            <xs:field xpath="ea:faNo"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="facancelNo">
            <xs:selector xpath="ea:fa"/>
            <xs:field xpath="ea:faNo"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="headerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="muk" type="ea:vknTcknType"/>
            <xs:element name="preparer" type="ea:vknTcknType"/>
            <xs:element name="reportNo">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:length value="36"/>
                        <xs:pattern
                            value="[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"
                        />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="periodStartdate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="periodEndDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="partStartDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="partEnddate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="partNo" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="vknType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="tcknType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="idType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="16"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}20[0-9]{2}[0-9]{9}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="vknTcknType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="vkn" type="ea:vknType"/>
            <xs:element name="tckn" type="ea:tcknType"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="personType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tuPerson" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="vkn" type="earsiv:vknType"/>
                        <xs:element name="title">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="realPerson" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="tckn" type="ea:tcknType"/>
                        <xs:element name="nameSurname">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="receiverType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tuPerson" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="vkn" type="ea:vknType"/>
                        <xs:element name="title">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="realPerson" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="tckn" type="ea:tcknType"/>
                        <xs:element name="nameSurname">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tsstNo" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="paymentTypeEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="paymentType">
        <xs:union memberTypes="ea:paymentTypeEnum ea:paymentTypeOther"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="timeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:time">
            <xs:pattern value="(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9]){2}(\.[0-9]+)?"/>
            <xs:minInclusive value="00:00:00"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the class that I use for validation:

```
    package com.meta.ea.adapter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.meta.ea.adapter.util.FormatterUtil;
import com.meta.ea.adapter.util.Matchers;
import com.meta.ea.model.type.CustomerType;
import com.meta.ea.model.type.InvoiceSendType;
import com.meta.ed.adapter.exception.EngineSystemException;
import com.meta.edefter.model.util.DateUtil;


public class XmlCreator {
    private static final Object NEW_LINE = "\r\n";
    private static final Object TAB = "\t";
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlCreator.class);
    ReportEngine engine ;

    public Connection conn;

    public XmlCreator(MetaFileWriter writer){
        this.engine = writer.processor.engine;
    }

    private CustomerType getCustomerType(String vknTckn){
        if (vknTckn.trim().length()==10) {
            return CustomerType.COMPANY;
        }else if(vknTckn.trim().length()==11) {
            return CustomerType.PERSON;
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String getFromDB(Map row, String columnName){
        return (row.get(columnName) == null) ? "" : row.get(columnName).toString();
    }

    private ResultSet getTaxResultFromDB(int invoiceId) {
        ResultSet selectTaxesResult = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement selectTaxesStatement;
            String selectTaxesQuery=IQuery.selectTaxesQuery;
            conn = createConnection();
            selectTaxesStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectTaxesQuery, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
            selectTaxesStatement.setInt(1, invoiceId);
            selectTaxesStatement.setFetchSize(ReportEngine.FETCH_SIZE_100);
            selectTaxesResult = selectTaxesStatement.executeQuery();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return selectTaxesResult;

    }

    private Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection connect = null;
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/datasource-definition-beans.xml");
        Object o = ctx.getBean("dataSource");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) o;
        connect = dataSource.getConnection();
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        return connect;
    }

    public String getEmptySignature(){
        return  "   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" Id=\"Signature_1\">\r\n" + 
                "       <ds:SignedInfo Id=\"SignedInfo_1\">\r\n" + 
                "           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod\r\n" + 
                "               Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments\" />\r\n" + 
                "           <ds:SignatureMethod\r\n" + 
                "               Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\" />\r\n" + 
                "           <ds:Reference URI=\"\">\r\n" + 
                "               <ds:Transforms>\r\n" + 
                "                   <ds:Transform\r\n" + 
                "                       Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature\" />\r\n" + 
                "               </ds:Transforms>\r\n" + 
                "               <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256\" />\r\n" + 
                "               <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>\r\n" + 
                "           </ds:Reference>\r\n" + 
                "           \r\n" + 
                "       </ds:SignedInfo>\r\n" + 
                "       <ds:SignatureValue Id=\"id1\">\r\n" + 
                "       </ds:SignatureValue>\r\n" +
                "       <ds:KeyInfo><ds:KeyValue><ds:RSAKeyValue><ds:Modulus/><ds:Exponent/></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue>" +
                "       <ds:X509Data><ds:X509SubjectName>dummy</ds:X509SubjectName><ds:X509Certificate/></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo>" +
                "       <ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties Target=\"Signature_1\"><xades:SignedProperties Id=\"SignedProperties_1\"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2013-01-28T12:04:41+02:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256\"/><ds:DigestValue>+VSgWjpP9XlNGk6EM7WYWzHXQ2xrzUZLas1QR+IS7Rc=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName></ds:X509IssuerName></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignerRole><xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole>Tedarikci</xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>" + 
                "       \r\n" + 
                "   </ds:Signature>";
    }

    public String getUniqueId() throws EngineSystemException{
        return engine.getUniqueueID();
    }

    public String getHeaderContent() throws EngineSystemException{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<ear xmlns:ea =\"http://www.efa.com.tr/ea.html\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://ea.efat.com.tr ea.xsd\" xmlns:xades=\"http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#\">").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append("<ear>");
        sb.append("<ea:header>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("VERSION", engine.getVersion())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("<ea:muk>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(TAB).append(getContent("MUK_VKN", engine.company.getVknTckn())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("</ea:muk>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("<ea:preparer>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(TAB).append(getContent("PREPARER_VKN", engine.getIntegratorVKN())).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append("</ea:preparer>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("REPORT_NO", engine.reportMasterDTO.getUuid())).append(NEW_LINE);
        String startOfPeriod= FormatterUtil.getFirstDayOfMountFromPeriod(engine.period).toString();
        String endOfPeriod= FormatterUtil.getLastDayOfMountFromPeriod(engine.period).toString();
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PERIOD_START_DATE", startOfPeriod)).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PERIOD_END_DATE", endOfPeriod)).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_START_DATE", DateUtil.formatDate(engine.processor.fwReport.getPartStartDate(), DateUtil.DATE_FORMAT_2))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_END_DATE", DateUtil.formatDate(engine.processor.fwReport.getPartEndDate(), DateUtil.DATE_FORMAT_2))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getContent("PART_NO", String.valueOf(engine.processor.fileIndex))).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(TAB).append(getEmptySignature()).append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append("</ea:header>").append(NEW_LINE);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder getContent(String property, String... values) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if(values!=null){
            if(values[0] ==null) return sb;
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

            int i=0;
            for(String value : values){
                parameters.put("ATTRIBUTE"+(i+1), value);
                i++;
            }

            sb.append(XmlTemplates.getString(property, parameters));
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public  XmlBuilder newEntryDetail(Map<String, Object> faturaRow) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<ea:fa>").append(NEW_LINE);
        sb.append(getInvoiceBody(faRow));
        sb.append(getTaxXml(faRow));
        sb.append(getCustomerInformation(faRow));
        sb.append(getInternetSaleInformation(faRow));
        sb.append("</ea:fa>").append(NEW_LINE);

        XmlBuilder xmlBuilder = new XmlBuilder(null);
        xmlBuilder.append(sb);
        return xmlBuilder;
    }

    //Some stuff..

    public String getFooterContent(){
        return "</ear>";
    }
}
```

And this is the the xml file that the above class creates:

```
    <ear xmlns:ea="http://www.efa.com/ea.html" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://ea.efa.com ea.xsd" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
<ear><ea:header>
    <ea:version>2.0</ea:version>
    <ea:muk>
        <ea:vkn>0510037140</ea:vkn>
    </ea:muk>
    <ea:preparer>
        <ea:vkn>6190524774</ea:vkn>
    </ea:preparer>
    <ea:reportNo>7BF70141-553A-40EE-896B-52D8F9E74765</ea:reportNo>
    <ea:periodStartDate>2015-06-01</ea:periodStartDate>
    <ea:periodEndDate>2015-06-30</ea:periodEndDate>
    <ea:partStartDate>2015-06-16</ea:periodStartDate>
    <ea:partEndDate>2015-06-16</ea:partEndDate>
    <ea:partNo>18</ea:partNo>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature_1">
        <ds:SignedInfo Id="SignedInfo_1">
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>

        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue Id="id1">
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo><ds:KeyValue><ds:RSAKeyValue><ds:Modulus/><ds:Exponent/></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue>     <ds:X509Data><ds:X509SubjectName>dummy</ds:X509SubjectName><ds:X509Certificate/></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo>     <ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties Target="Signature_1"><xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties_1"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2013-01-28T12:04:41+02:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>+VSgWjpP9XlNGk6EM7WYWzHXQ2xrzUZLas1QR+IS7Rc=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509SerialNumber>586340106507</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignerRole><xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>        
    </ds:Signature>
</ea:header>
    //Some stuff..
</ear>
```

I couldn't figure out which point that I miss.How I should I modify my xml creator class to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema has a target namespace although that part of your code looks broken as posted (`targetNamespace="http://ea .efa.com` lacks a closing quote and the space inside the URL also looks suspicious). A target namespace means that the root of your XML instance document should be in that namespace, so you would need `<ear xmlns="target-namespace-goes-here" ...>...</ear>`.

Comment: I modified the code according to your explanations.It worked now.Thank you so much.